# Why is my Python code not highlighted?

Tags: support, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

I have posted the following code in [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447954/why-mathbfi-n-mathbfa-top-mathbfa-mathbfx-is-gaussian-with-i-i):

```python
import numpy as np

for i in range(3):
    n = np.random.randint(2, 10000)
    m = np.random.randint(1, n)

    A = np.random.randn(m, n) * ((1 / m) ** 0.5)
    x = np.random.rand(n,)
    e = np.matmul(np.eye(n) - np.matmul(np.transpose(A, [1, 0]), A), x)  # (I-A'A)x

    print(np.linalg.norm(x) * ((1/m) ** 0.5))
    print(np.std(e))
    print('===')

    try:
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        import seaborn
        plt.cla()
        seaborn.histplot(e, bins=300)
        plt.title('mean = %f, var = %f' % (float(e.mean()), float(e.std())))
        plt.savefig('%d.png' % i, dpi=300)
    except:
        pass
```

It seems that the code is successfully highlighted here, but not in [my original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4447954/why-mathbfi-n-mathbfa-top-mathbfa-mathbfx-is-gaussian-with-i-i). I just use the same codes in these two places:

````
(my original code is without any ~)

~```python
import numpy as np

for i in range(3):
    n = np.random.randint(2, 10000)
    m = np.random.randint(1, n)

    A = np.random.randn(m, n) * ((1 / m) ** 0.5)
    x = np.random.rand(n,)
    e = np.matmul(np.eye(n) - np.matmul(np.transpose(A, [1, 0]), A), x)  # (I-A'A)x

    print(np.linalg.norm(x) * ((1/m) ** 0.5))
    print(np.std(e))
    print('===')

    try:
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        import seaborn
        plt.cla()
        seaborn.histplot(e, bins=300)
        plt.title('mean = %f, var = %f' % (float(e.mean()), float(e.std())))
        plt.savefig('%d.png' % i, dpi=300)
    except:
        pass
~```
````

A similar phenomenon is observed in [my another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420630/convergence-analysis-of-a-vector-sequence-with-discretization-recurrences-with). And here I am even not sure if this is caused by my browser or some other reasons from myself?

Comment: FWIW, you could use [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUU1rwzAMvedXCEaJXNy0XdllkEOO-w1jB7dxMoO_sN2S_PvJSdoSOoGxeO9JfrKU8S4ksFfjRxARrC-KzgVQoCwEYXuJJ_ZZAIWFmuiKwNaZ6VI24TuH44GCTRrzr-bIwbJiEjQvAosm07AFxCPswVC6hUP1MXccXgrQ8pmSM2VEMleNlMlRInXardFERdG7KLHh8E1eDj-MQ0NnYABvgF-7pmzYMBv0ITumMq2s0H1lXTA4LPb2T3NsrY6pRbkCy7quy2XqFMb5D3N0wRkge167pNUZ1LwCP2Yg78Dr9BAvZJTi7IJ9wCSpLlogeyCLovpVceqMksNZ2Vif7ru51yWVtMTSSJE3uuk43ESYshI2gJ12gqqrzCOjX7oDeUTG2LpZFDfZqR7LTVt52-cOikPr1fNdOVykT8_5vYjxD87Zrug=&lang=python) to make a live version of your code, with syntax highlighting.